# Why did Claire change her hair color to black and then later back to blonde?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

After their first real fight between Francis and Claire, Claire changed her hair color to black. She kept it like this for a few episodes and then changed it back to blonde. What is the underlying meaning of this?